# Camera Permission doesn't work at run time

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, camera

I am working on QR code scanner App which takes user credentials and scan QR code and store User credentials with the content on QR code.

Since, I am beginner on working with Android App Development and hence, facing several issues such as:

(i) While opening camera permissions in App, it doesn't start automatically.I need to restart the app to open the camera to start QR code scanning.

Is there any possibility through which my app opens camera without taking permission from user. I have seen many apps doing so.

Or is there any modifications I can do to my QR scanner Java file so my camera works on runtime permission :qrscan.java

```
package com.example.android.loginapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.loginapp.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.PackageManagerWrapper;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class qrscan extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button takePictureButton;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    TextView textView;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.qrcode);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this,barcodeDetector).setRequestedPreviewSize(640,480).build();

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(qrscan.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    cameraSource.start(holder);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if(qrCodes.size()!=0){
                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                            textView.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

(ii)  My second issue is that: I want to store credentials of user with the QR code. But I lack knowledge of database and all those stuff. 
Is there any easy way through which I can store such data ?
Something like storing data on google cloud.

I have already seen similar questions on stack overflow but none of them solves my issue.

This question is similar but doesn't help : [surface view does not show camera after i gave permission](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47573182/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for permission to camera in activity where you have qr reader functionality before you start using it. If application do not have permission to that device you push it for ask again or just ignore it and let user know about it by message.
Example code

```
private void permissionAsk(String permission){
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
        permissionAsk(permission);
        permissionAsk(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        permissionAsk(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

You can easly find more solutions like that almost ready to go.

Comment: For storage you can use `android shared preferences` or `firebase`. The first is stored locally on your phone. Last one is Google dedicated cloud. You can fine multiple tutorials online for them. Ofc firebase is quite more complex because it need to some configuration but it still can be found on yt for example.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for camera permission,since allowing doesn't make camera open automatically .I need to restart my app to use scanner

Comment: Because you don't check after you get permission for result. After permission is successfully granted you start your scanner. You need to override onRequestPermissionsResult. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-request-permissions-in-android-application/amp/ should helps.